# Can you use PowerPoint images on your website?

Tags: website-design, images, licensing

Is it all right to use powerpoint images on your website?    For example, If I draw an arrow using the shapes tool, can I then cut the image from the powerpoint and save it, Then use it on my website?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you may.
I contacted Microsoft support and they confirmed this.
However, I don't know how much trust I would put into a chat representative for legal concerns. So, I've provided some more information...

[Here is an excerpt](http://www.microsoft.com/About/Legal/EN/US/IntellectualProperty/Permissions/Default.aspx#ELC) from Microsoft's own website:

> Clip Art and Sample Art
>
> The End-User
>   License Terms that accompany your
>   software **describe the permitted
>   commercial uses of images, clip art,
>   animations, sounds, music, shapes,
>   video clips, and templates that
>   accompanied the product.** Find End-User
>   License Terms for Microsoft products.
>
> The Clip Art and Media gallery
>   provides a compilation of artwork. See
>   the use terms for the description of
>   permitted uses. If those terms do not
>   meet your needs, our Clip Art partners
>   at Office Online provide a variety of
>   images you can license directly.
>
> In the absence of language to the
>   contrary in the License Agreement,
>   Sample Art (which includes images
>   customarily found in the "sample"
>   folders within Microsoft operating
>   systems) may be used for personal use
>   only. You may not sell, lease, or
>   distribute Sample Art, or any
>   materials you create that use Sample
>   images, for any commercial purposes.

Additionally, here is an excerpt straight from PowerPoint 2007 EULA:

> Media Elements and Templates. You may
>   copy and use images, clip art,
>   animations, sounds, music, shapes,
>   video clips and templates provided
>   with the software and identified for
>   such use in documents and projects
>   that you create. **You may distribute
>   those documents and projects
>   noncommercially**. If you wish to use
>   these media elements or templates for
>   any other purpose, go to
>   www.microsoft.com/permission to learn
>   whether that use is allowed.

You may find out additional details [here](http://www.microsoft.com/About/Legal/EN/US/IntellectualProperty/Permissions/Default.aspx).
For any further inquires I was suggested to contact microsoft directly, in writing, at:

Microsoft Corporation

One Microsoft Way

Redmond, WA 98052-6399

Comment: Note that "commercial use" is an annoyingly vague term. Interpreted broadly, it might cover even such seemingly innocuous things as using an image on a website that also has an ad banner on it, or indeed using it for _any_ purpose at a for-profit company.

Answer (score 2):

To expand upon Johannes' answer, a simple arrow like you describe in your question is not likely to pass the [threshold of originality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threshold_of_originality).

The details vary between jurisdictions, but for example, the [Compendium of U.S. Copyright Office Practices](http://ipmall.info/hosted_resources/CopyrightCompendium/chapter_0500.asp) states, in section 503.02(a), "Minimal standards: pictorial or graphic
material":

> "Similarly, it is not possible to copyright common geometric r. figures or shapes such as the hexagon or the ellipse, a standard symbol such as an arrow or a five-pointed star."

Thus, you can safely use your arrow without having to worry about copyright issues.  Of course, if it was a *really* fancy arrow, with a substantially original design, the situation might be different.